# Backtrack 4 repository?

Tags: 10.04, repository

I check to add Backtrack 4 repository on my ubuntu lucid lynx 10.04 LTS installation to add some tools that come with Backtrack 4 easily ...

Various websites talk about it but none work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested it but this should work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.offensive-security.com pwnsauce main microverse macroverse restricted universe multiverse'
wget -q http://archive.offensive-security.com/backtrack.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

**Edit**: I think this would work but it appears to be 32bit-only at this juncture. There may be another repo that caters for 64bit but I can't find it.

**Edit 2**: This works perfectly on a 32bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it work for 64-bits or not (referring to your second edit) ?

Comment: @Lekensteyn No. There's probably some way to force the arch but by default it won't work.

Comment: you should remove your second edit (`Edit 2:` ...) to take away some confusion :) I thought you were sleeping and meant 64bit ;)